# How to find only links in a textbox using Jquery

Tags: jquery, textbox, jquery-selectors

I am trying to write some code that will search a textbox which a user can type in and remove any text that is not contained with in a link/a href tag.

For example:

```
$("#ugc").focusout(function() {
 var ugcText = $(this).val;
 // Function to remove anything not in an a tag
 $("#ugc").val(function output);
})
```

So if #ugc.val equaled something like:

```
Some text <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a> Some more text <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">Another Link</a>
```

The value after running the function would be:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">Another Link</a>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working:

```
$("#uspcontent").focusout(function(){
  var uspText = $(this).val();
  $("#tempDiv").html(uspText);
  var tempDiv = $("#tempDiv");
  var allLinks = tempDiv.find("a");
  var output = $("#tempDiv").empty().append(allLinks).html();
  $("#uspcontent").val(output);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```
var ugcText  = $('#ugc').val();
var $tempDiv = $('<div>').html(ugcText);

var $allLinks = $tempDiv.find('a');

$('#ugc').text($tempDiv.empty().append($allLinks).html());
```

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6852kxj2/)

Comment: I had to modify your code a bit to get it to work properly for me. For some reason I was getting an error with the $tempDiv '<div>' portion of the variable. My solution was to create an actual temporary div on the page, have it not display and then do the same procedure. See code below.